# Problems with wifi on lenovo yoga 3 pro running fedora

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, wifi-driver

I recently purchased a lenovo yoga pro 3, and installed linux mint on it instead of windows. Mint didn't work very well however, lacking drivers for many of the yoga's features like the touchscreen, so I tried upgrading the kernel. This fixed some things and broke others, including the wifi. (**the wifi did initially work however**)

I tried all of the minty troubleshooting I could find, but finally decided to try another of my favorite distros, fedora. Everything works perfectly now, except wifi.

**So the wifi card CAN be linux compatible**, but apparently only with outdated mint running proprietary drivers. I would like to get the wifi working on fedora so that I am only working on fixing one issue instead of five.

Has anyone any idea if I can use mint's drivers in fedora or have any other solution to my problem?

As for as I can tell the onboard wifi card is broadcom.

<sub>It's also worth noting that I have tried debian mint and ubuntu and both failed miserably.</sub>

Comment: Before installing mint did you make sure the WiFi worked in windows  to confirm the card is good?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine.

Comment: Is there a particular reason a question like this would be in the negatives??

Answer (score 1):

FC21 on Yoga 3 WIFI works, see this:

http://niteshnarayanlal.blogspot.hk/2014/11/setting-up-fedora-to-work-with-broadcom.html

Also, power saving on my Yoga3 is wonderful with FC21, see this:

https://plus.google.com/108110137184055365183/posts/CmsjAfNMw6p

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! Unfortunately I still haven't gotten it to work. using the information provided by the other answer I was able to install the driver, but it doesn't seem to be running, even after reboot and confirmation of installation. It might be relevant that my card is actually a 01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with this for the past couple of days, with the Yoga 3 Pro, with a fresh install of Fedora 21. I'm assuming you're using your phone to tether the machine to the internet and ran "yum update" after installing. Like other people/sites have said, installing kmod-wl from the terminal does work as root. If your install is like mine, the problem is an issue of kernel compatibility. Installing akmod-wl would theoretically have been another good idea (as it rebuilds the module with the kernal in mind, but for some reason it didn't work for me. Try "yum install kmod-wl-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.x86_64" and reboot the system from there. Just doing "yum install kmod-wl" points to kmod-wl-3.17.6-300.fc21.x86_64.x86_64. I'm too new to figure out how to update the kernel to that version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I feel like I am a lot closer!! i have the driver installed but it isn't running on start up, or any other time for that matter. Is there anything else you might have done that would cause the driver to load and the wireless card to use it?

Comment: I've done a lot of things to try to get it to work before I realized the kernel difference, and learned a lot of new things. After I added the RPM fusion repositories (free and non-free, kmod-wl would be in the "non-free" category) I tried installing kmod-wl first, then I removed it and installed akmod-wl, then I removed that and installed the one above. I added a lot of development tools, theoretically to try and build the driver from the makefiles from [this address](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.248.txt), but I'm pretty sure they wouldn't do anything to help.